# Ubuntu constantly losing IP address

Tags: server, dhcp, ip

I'm pretty new to Linux in general, so I don't know if this is a common issue or not. I setup Ubuntu 16.04 as my Plex server. After about 24 hours usually it will lose internet connection. When I check the network connection I see that there isn't an IP address assigned, information is all blank. After disabling and re-enabling the connection it is assigned an IP address and it comes back up.

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu and I have no really changed any settings for the system. It is a home network connected to a router using DHCP for IP assignments.

This is becoming frustrating and was wondering if there is a permanent solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Anything in syslog? `grep dhclient /etc/log/syslog`

Comment: Same problem here. Nothing in syslog other than dhclient starting up and reacquiring the address after I disable and switch back on. Did you find a fix?

Comment: oh, and it was `grep dhclient /var/log/syslog`